# Make an equation true by moving one of the cards

Tags: puzzle

I came accross with this puzzle:

There is an equation written in cards so that every card represent a number or a mathematical symbol. Move one of the cards so that equation is true. The equation looks like this:

$2 * ( 5 - 1 ) * 3 = \mathrm{3}^{3}$

Here symbol * means multiplication. I am stumped with this question. The moving of the card is in my opinion ill-defined operation as if you move for example number 1 then there is minus - sign left alone. Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: **Hint:** $3^3 = 9\times 3$

Answer (score 4):

Moving the left hand bracket gives the correct equation
$$(2\times5-1)\times3=3^3$$

Comment: I feel so silly now :-) ! Thanks!